# Integration without using parametrization .

Tags: complex-analysis, parametric

I would like to integrate the following line integral without using parametrization . 
I wanted to integrate the following $$\int_C \frac{1}{z-a} dz$$ , where $C$ is a a curve along $|z-a| =r$ .

Using parametrization i can easily get the answer , but i wanted to integrate without using parametrization of the circle. Appreciate your hints .

Comment: For that you'll need the Cauchy (complex ) Integration Theorems. Have you already studied these?

Comment: @DonAntonio : I know what it says and from that i can easily get that it will be $2\pi i$ But essentially there is again some parametrization used . I would like to do it explicitly without using parametrization . Is it possible . consider a case $\mathbb R^2$ , $\int xy^2$ along the curve $x^2+y^2=4$. representing it into polar co-ordinates i can easily get the answer but i am looking forward doing it without any parametrization .

Comment: I really can't understand what you mean, @Complex: both in complex and real analysis, either you go by the *definition* of line integral and you parametrize then, or else you use some theorem (Cauchy, Green, etc.) to evaluate the integral....how else?!

Comment: @DonAntonio: Sir, Do you mean to say that i cannot get line integral without parametrization . Consider $\int_c f(z) dz$ is the line integral to be evaluated , now i write dz=dx+idy . Can i integrate without considering parametrization $y=y(t)$ and $x=x(x)$  ?

Comment: under certain condition you **can** but you'll have to rely on well-known theorems to get  Riemann Integral, or residues in the complex case or stuff.

Comment: @DonAntonio : Ok , thank you . Sir , I just looked on wikipedia the $C=|x-a|=r$ gets changed to $0$ to $2\pi$ as limits , how do i get that ?

Comment: Parametrizing, @Complex ! You parametrize the circle $\;|z-a|=r\;$ with center $\;a\;$ and radius $\;r\;$ by substituting (parametrizing!) $\;z=a+re^{it}\;,\;\;0\le t\le 2\pi\;$ ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may assume $a=0$. Consider an integer $N\gg1$, put $\omega:=e^{2\pi i/N}$ (an $N$th root of unity) and choose $z_k:=r\omega^k\in\partial D_r$ $\>(0\leq k\leq N)$. Then using the "physical interpretation" of a line integral one has
$$\eqalign{\int_{\partial D_r}{dz\over z}&\doteq\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}{z_{k+1}-z_k\over z_k}=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}{r\omega^{k+1}-r\omega^k\over r\omega^k}\cr  &=N(\omega-1)=2\pi i\>{e^{2\pi i/N}-1\over{2\pi i/N}}\to 2\pi i\quad(N\to\infty)\ .\cr}$$

Here is a second approach to the problem:

On the right half plane the principal value $z\mapsto {\rm Log}\>z$ is a primitive of $z\mapsto {1\over z}$. It follows that the integral over the circular arc $\gamma_1$ from $re^{-i\pi/4}$ to $re^{-i\pi/4}$ is given by
$$\int_{\gamma_1}{dz\over z}={\rm Log}\bigl(re^{i\pi/4}\bigr)-{\rm Log}\bigl(re^{i\pi/4}\bigr)=i{\pi\over2}\ .$$

Similarly, on the upper half plane the principal value $z\mapsto {\rm Log}\>{z\over i}$ is a primitive of $z\mapsto {1\over z}$. It follows that the integral over the circular arc $\gamma_2$ from $re^{i\pi/4}$ to $re^{3i\pi/4}$ is given by
$$\int_{\gamma_2}{dz\over z}={\rm Log}{re^{3i\pi/4}\over i}-{\rm Log}{re^{i\pi/4}\over i}=i{\pi\over2}\ .$$
And so on.

Comment: Putting $\;z_k:=rw^k\;$ is just a not-so-hidden way to parametrize...!

Comment: @Christian Blatter : How do you evaluate the limit ? Its not continuous so there is no way of using any theorems involving continuity ?

Comment: @DonAntonio : After the discussion with you i decided to accept the answer even though the proof uses parametrization .

Comment: Oh, that's fine @ComplexAnalysis ! In fact, Christian deserves that because he showed you a rather unusual way to solve the integral. The sum is basically the difference of two geometric sums, and then the limit is the usual thing. There's no question of continuity here.